# javascript auto page link change in loop with time left till next reload

Tags: javascript, loops, intervals

I want to change the link after 30sec.

Example - I have an array containing 4 websites which are -

```
var links = ["www.facebook.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.twitter.com", "www.linkedin.com"];
```

Now, I want to open facebook then youtube then twitter then Linkedin website with 30sec interval in the same window.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iframes` to do it as follows -

```js
var links = ["www.facebook.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.twitter.com", "www.linkedin.com"];

let index=0;
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(links[index]);
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = links[index];
  index=(index+1)%4;
},30000);
```

```html
<iframe id='iframe' src="https://www.webpagetest.org/" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></iframe>
```

Although the above code is cycling through the list of websites, it isn't getting anything to display. However, Youtube, google, and such websites don't allow iframes to their site. They block iframes to show their website. I don't think there's any other easy way to do it since once you redirect the user, you can't redirect from the website you redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to your first link, the page context is lost and so is any setInterval you had set.

So this is not possible unless you're using an extension which will work in a separate context.

Comment: Can you recommend some extensions?